# Correct Library Usage: requests w/ bs4.BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, tags, request, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I just switched from using `urllib2` as my HTTP access library to using the `request` library. In urllib you use `BeautifulSoup` to pull the html elements using the `findAll(tag='element')` function, do I continue using BeautifulSoup the same way or does request have a function that simplifies this process?

---

Pulling tags using urllib2

---

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/')
soup = BS(response)

for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    print a['href]
```

---

Pulling tags using request

---

```
import response

response = request.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')

for a in response.findAll('a'):
    print a['href]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[request](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) only makes it easier to get the data from a URL, especially if there are redirects, etc. It doesn't parse the body of the `HTML` for you, you still should do that with `BeautifulSoup` and add the import for it to you second code fragment, and something like:

```
soup = BS(response.text)
```